Range of arguments lengths / nargs in python click
Is there a way to allow a range of arguments in click using nargs, such exactly between 2 and 4 arguments? Something like the following, for example, in a test.py file:
@click.group()
@click.argument("ints", nargs=(2, 4))
def test(ints):
    ...

test()

Which would then allow:
./test.py 1 2
./test.py 1 2 3
./test.py 1 2 3 4

But disallow:
./test.py 1
./test.py 1 2 3 4 5

